# Does this distribution have a name

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I could not find the name of the following distribution after searching for a while:
$$f(x) = ka^k/(x+a)^{(k+1)}$$ for $x \gt 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the Pareto distribution with shape parameter $k$ and location paramerer $a$. More precisely, If $X$ follows Pareto($k$,$a$), then your distribution is the distribution of $X-a$.

Comment: Yes, reread my answer. OP's distribution is the distribution of $X-a$, where $X$ is Pareto.